# $X = ABA^T$, $X$ is PSD and $B$ is Symmetric. Does $B$ have to be PSD to satisfy this equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization

Assume that I have given $X = ABA^T$.

Also assume $X$ is PSD and $B$ is Symmetric with all diagonal elements equal to 1. Does $B$ also have to be PSD to satisfy this equation?

Edit1:
PSD means positive semi definite matrix and $A \neq 0$.

Edit2:
Let's assume that there is no column in A with all zeros. A is a data matrix ($ \in n \times d$ ). If all elements in the particular column are zero then I can safely delete that column.

Edit3: 
All diagonal elements of B are 1.

Comment: Does PSD mean positive semi-definite?  If so, consider the case when $A = 0$.

Comment: updated the question. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: So suppose $B = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$ and $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: Let's assume that there is no column in A with all zeros. A is a data matrix ($ \in n \times d$). If all elements in the particular column are zero then I can safely delete that column). I'm not sure if a row entry with all zeros is a valid data point or not. But I think theoretically it is possible.

Comment: Also, assume that all diagonal elements of B are 1.

Comment: Take $B$ to be any symmetric matrix, some of whose eigenvalues are positive, and some of whose eigenvalues are negative.  Let $A$ be the orthogonal projection onto the space spanned by eigenvectors corresponding to eigenvalues that are positive.  So, for example, start with $B = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.  Then $A = 2^{-1/2} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1\\-1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ will work (and you don't need the $2^{-1/2}$ - that's just to make it a projection).

Answer (score 0):

By assumption $x^T X x = x^T A B A^T x \geq 0$ for all $x$. Let $y = A^T x$. Then, for $X$ to be PSD, $y^T B y$ must be nonnegative for all $y \in \text{Im}(A^T)$. It is obvious that this is the case when $B$ is PSD, but this condition is actually weaker.